# embedding a DTC in a vmlinux/bzImage

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot, device-tree, initrd

I need to boot Linux on some custom hardware using uboot.  For development I'm booting it using:

```
bootm <image-addr> <ramdisk-addr> <dtc-addr>
```

However, in the field I would like to collapse all three items into one.  (legacy hardware, etc.)

Collapsing the ramdisk into the kernel is easy enough, but I've only seen vague references to getting a DTC in there in a useful way.

Could someone suggest a way to do this, or at least point me at some documentation that would help?  I'd hate to crawl through the source only to find out there was a recipe online.

Answer (score 0):

And as usual posting the question leads to me finding the answer an hour later.  An explanation of how to build and boot this type of image with uBoot can be found at:

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/denx/u-boot/doc/uImage.FIT/